# table columns are not visible in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 10 columns in a table in *iReport* **Design view.**

In **Preview**  it generated a report where I get to see only 7 columns of the table. The last 3 columns are not visible (truncated).

How to fix it?

Comment: Probably they're out of the current page.

Comment: Change the size of your paper maybe?

Comment: where do you change it ? what is the menu please ?  you know I already have 'Adapt to Parent'  to my table.....still not working....I'm using latest  iReport 5.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the name of the report on Report Inspector. Right Click on the same, select properties.
Modify the Width and Height. After modifications, preview and adjust the height and width accordingly.